# Как избежать ромбического наследования когда нужно в двух классах реализовать общую функцию общего предка?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, проектирование

Допустим у нас есть иерархия абстрактрых классов:

```
/*
    Item
    |
    |
    ------- Object
    |
    |------ Link
*/
```

Например:

```
class Item
{
public:
    World *world() = 0;
};

//-----------------------------------------------

class Object : public Item
{
public:
    virtual ObjectValue calculate() = 0;
    virtual void connectTo(const QString &objectId, const QString &linkDefId) = 0;
};

//-----------------------------------------------

class Link : public Item
{
public:
    virtual QString fromObjectId() const = 0;
    virtual QString toObjectId() const = 0;
    virtual QString linkDefId() const = 0;
};
```

И вот нужно реализовать классы `Object` и `Link`. Например, семейство клиентских классов:

```
class ClientObject : public Object
{
    //...
};

//-----------------------------------------------

class ClientLink : public Link
{
    //...
};
```

и семейство серверных классов:

```
class ServerObject : public Object
{
    //...
};

//-----------------------------------------------

class ServerLink : public Link
{
    //...
};
```

Тогда как реализовать функцию `World *Item::world()`, если она должна работать одинково **внутри** семейства классов имплиминтации `Client[ClassName]` и одинаково внутри `Client[ClassName]`, но различаться **между** семействами `Server[ClassName]` и `Server[ClassName]`? (Подразумевается, что могут унаследоваться другие семейства и для каждого из них функция `World *Item::world()` должна быть имплиминтированно одинаково для классов внутри этого семейства.)

Например в Java проблема бы решалась использованием разных слов для наследования `implements` и `extentds`. Каким образом можно выкрутиться в C++? Конечно, возможно описать `ClientObject::world()` и `ClientLink::world()` идентично, но вы же понимаете, что это некошерно.

Comment: Если она одинакова для всех Client, то она одинакова и для Object и Link, так? (Если нет - то вы бы ее реализовывали в этих классах по-разному, и вопроса бы не было). А если она одинакова и там - ну так реализуйте ее в Item, что мешает? :)

Comment: @Harry Одинаково внутри семейства, но различаются между семействами. То есть у `ClientObject` и `ClientLink` должна быть одинакова и для `ServerObject` и `ServerLink` тоже одинакова, но, например, между `ClientXxx` и `ServerXxx` будет различаться (буду править вопрос, чтобы уточнить этот момент)

Comment: Тогда вряд ли вы избежите ромбовидности - у вас есть различия Object-Link и Client-Server... Только вот множественное наследование обычно так редко нужно, что наводит на мысли о перепроектировании - точно ли у вас выполняются отношения ЯВЛЯЕТСЯ? Может, тут достаточно обойтись отношением СОДЕРЖИТ? на самом ли деле такая сложная иерархия отражает реальные явления или она просто выбрана для того, чтобы объединить одинаковый код?

Comment: Создайте класс ClientItem и ServerItem, там реализуйте вашу функцию нужную образом, далее наследуйтесь от этих классов

Comment: Подождите, непонятно. (Возможно, я недопонял вопрос.) Почему нельзя просто имплементировать `world()` один раз в `Object` и один раз в `Link`? Раз имплементации разные, этого не избежать всё равно. И тут я не вижу покамест ромба.

Comment: @VladD нельзя непосредственно в `Object` и `Link`, она по разному должна быть реализована в `Client...` и `Server...`

Comment: @asianirish: Ну тогда я за mixin. В ответе Chorkov это один из вариантов.

Comment: @asianirish  Я что-то совершенно не понял, что такое Client[ClassName]  и что такое "Client[ClassName] и одинаково внутри Client[ClassName]"? В чем между ними различие?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вариант 1: 
Если реализация тривиальная однострочная ( например, getName() ), то и copy/paste не грех.

Вариант 2:
Не будем отделять дерево интерфейсов от дерева наследования реализации. Т.е. реализуем `Item::world` прямо в Item.

Вариант 3: 
Реализуем базовую функциональность заданного интерфейса, в отдельном объекте, не наследуемом от интерфейса.

```
class ImplItem {
 World *world(){ ... }
};
class ClientLink : public Link, private ImplItem
{
  public: 
   using ImplItem::world;
}
```

Минусы: using придется повторить для всех функций интерфейса. (copy/paste).
Не все среды разработки адекватно рефакторят этот код (если захочешь переименовать функцию или изменить список аргументов).

Вариант 4:
Тоже что и в 3, но агрегирование вместо наследования:

```
class ClientLink : public Link 
{
  ImplItem implItem;
  public: 
   World *world() { return implItem.world(); } // copy/paste, но однострочная
}
```

Минусы: copy/paste - больше чем в варианте 3.

Вариант 5:
Зачем вам наследование интерфейсов?
Например:

```
class Item
{
public:
    virtual World *world() = 0;
};
class Object  //: public Item
{
public:
    virtual Item* item() =0 // но, даже это может не понадобиться. или тривиально реализовываться: 
       // { return dyndamic_cast<Item*>(this); }
    virtual ObjectValue calculate() = 0;
    virtual void connectTo(const QString &objectId, const QString &linkDefId) = 0;
};

class ClientLink : public Link, private ClientItem {... };
```

Минусы: наследование интерфейсов иногда действительно нужно.

Вариант 6:
Шаблонная реализация (Mixin-Based Programming)

```
template<typename Base>
class ImplItem : public Base {
 World *world(){ ... }
};
class ServerObject : public ImplItem<Object>
{
    //...
};
```

минусы: не все среды разработки адекватно строят дерево наследования.

Вариант 7:
Шаблонная реализация, ATL/WTL style (кроме этих двух библиотек, нигде более не видел.)
В отличии от предыдущего варианта, ImplItem в своем конструкторе видит полностью сконструированный объект, т.е. может вызвать виртуальные функции ServerObjectPart, что может оказаться важным, с привычками "после джавы".

```
template<typename Base>
class ImplItem : public Base {
 World *world(){ ... }
};
class ServerObjectPart : public Object
{
    //...      World *world() НЕ реализована.
};
typedef ImplItem<ServerObjectPart> ServerObject; 
//...
new ServerObject();
```

Comment: Прием примеси класса тут оптимальный, спасибо за заданное направление!